# TypeScript Loading image texture to skybox via file input

Tags: typescript, webgl

**What I want to do**

I have a default image (local file) used as a texture to a skybox (using webgl with TypeScript). I also have a file input in the HTML outside the Canvas.

I want, that the user selects another local file, using the file input, and the new local file is used as the skybox texture.

**Code**

The relevant code (in `src/graphics/drawItems.ts`) is :

```
    //--------------- skybox cube variable positions ------------------//
    skyPositionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(skyProgram, "a_position");       // as marked above , the typescript will grab on "a_positions"
                                                                                // the vertex data will go there
    skyboxLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(skyProgram, "u_skybox");             // same here in the fragmentshader
    viewDirectionProjectionInverseLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(skyProgram, "u_viewDirectionProjectionInverse");
                                                                                // here the inverse projection matrix will go



    skyPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();                                      // create the first position buffer. It is empty now
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, skyPositionBuffer);                          // sent the buffer to GL

    var positions = new Float32Array(
        [
        -1, -1,
        1, -1,
        -1,  1,
        -1,  1,
        1, -1,
        1,  1,
        ]
    );                                                                          // These are the positions for a cube
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);                  // bind the values of positions with the last buffer created

    var texture = gl.createTexture();                                           // Texture from 2D images
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);                               // Wrap around a cube

    const faceInfos = [                                                         // make an array
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
        },
        {
        target: gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z,
        },
    ];


    faceInfos.forEach((faceInfo) => {
        const {target} = faceInfo;                                              // faceinfos (plural) is an array.
                                                                                // each item will return a tuple

        const level = 0;
        const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
        const width = 512;                                                      // height and width should be a power of 2
        const height = 512;
        const format = gl.RGBA;
        const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;

                                                                                // setup each face so it's immediately renderable
        gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, width, height, 0, format, type, null);                 // use built in GL functions

        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(target, level, internalFormat, format, type, assets.loadedAssets[0]);                 // skybox is loadedassets 0
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);

    });


    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);                  // until images have loaded, use this option


    gl.useProgram(skyProgram);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(skyPositionLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, skyPositionBuffer);


    var size = 2;                                                                                           // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;                                                                                    // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false;                                                                                  // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;                                                                                         // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;                                                                                         // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(skyPositionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);



    var aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;

    var viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix = [
        0.33781543374061584, 0, 0.6931547522544861,4.863637048657665e-9,
        0, 0.5773502588272095, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, -0.499750018119812,
        -0.8989261984825134, 0, -0.43810003995895386, 0.5002500414848328];

​

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( viewDirectionProjectionInverseLocation, false, viewDirectionProjectionInverseMatrix);

    gl.uniform1i(skyboxLocation, 0);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
```

Then later in same file :

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 1 * 6);
```

**EDIT** I should add: `assets.loadedAssets[0]` is a string indicating full relative path to an image.

Then in `src/generic/inputControls.ts`

```
onst skyBoxLoader = document.getElementById("skybox") as HTMLInputElement;
skyBoxLoader.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

    // if (skyBoxLoader.files.length > 0){
    //  assets.loadedAssets[0] = URL.createObjectURL(skyBoxLoader.files[0]);
    //  drawing.createDrawQueue();
    // }
    // //alert(URL.createObjectURL(skyBoxLoader.files[0]));

    var filePath = skyBoxLoader.value;
    console.log(filePath);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        assets.loadedAssets[0] = e.target.result;  //NOTE THIS LINE
        console.log(assets.loadedAssets[0]);
        drawing.createDrawQueue();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(skyBoxLoader.files[0]);

});
```

The full code maybe found in : [GitHub here](https://github.com/naturalmechanics/webgltests/tree/main/project). The index.html file is under `build`, and the typescripts are under `src/graphics`, resp `src/generic` etc.

**Error and attempt to solution**

If I do what I have done above, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D: Argument 6 is not valid for any of the 6-argument overloads.
    prepareSkyBox drawItems.ts:216
    prepareSkyBox drawItems.ts:201
    setupSkyBox drawItems.ts:268
    createDrawQueue drawItems.ts:291
    onload input_controls.ts:80
    EventHandlerNonNull* input_controls.ts:77
    EventListener.handleEvent* input_controls.ts:66
drawItems.ts:216:5
```

The blob url is :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD ..... very long string
```

I also tried to use `assets.loadedAssets[0] = e.target.result;` as well as `filePath` (in code i commented the line as NOTE THIS LINE)

**Question**

How do I change the skybox texture based on user input? Google did not help.

Thank you